# Execute DataTables or re-draw tables after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When user click o a link it gets the ajax executed, when I get from the ajax result is an html which contains div's and tables, actually is just one table... I want to use the library DataTables for this particular result

```
<html>
<body>
<ul>
 <li><a href="#" id="link1">Click</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="results" id="result1"></div>

<script>
$("#link1").on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault;
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: { id: ids},
    dataType: 'html',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
         $('#result1).html(data);
    },
        error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        }
    })
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So everything the ajax will output is a basic html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
     <h4>Some title</h4>
     <h5>A sub-title...</h5>

     <div class="table-responsive">
       <table class="table" id="ajax_table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Some 1</th>
              <th>Some 2</th>
              <th>Some 3</th>
            </tr>
           </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>T1</td>
              <td>T2</td>
              <td>T3</td>
            </tr>
            // a whole bunch of rows.. about 100...
          </tbody>
       </table>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So how can I use the DataTables to "re-draw" that table from the ajax?...
Datatables libraries are loaded before anything else alone with a CSS, jquery, bootstraps, etc... I can ask the other guys where the table is formed to add the datatable script

```
$('#ajax_table').DataTable({
    dom: 'Blfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]
});
```

But then how do I executed since it will came with the html and the script?...

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinitialized datatables after ajax success

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: {
        id: ids
    },
    dataType: 'html',
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#result1).html(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
    })
})
$('#ajax_table').dataTable().fnDestroy();
$('#ajax_table').dataTable({
    "aoColumns": [{
            "bSortable": false
        },
        null, null, null, null
    ]
});
```